Can selenium grid nodes auto-restart when their IP address changes?
I use selenium grid to run automated tests, with one physical machine acting as hub+node and two other physical workstations acting as additional nodes. I've noticed lately that the two node-only machines will randomly drop their connection to the hub overnight, even though the machines themselves have not been restarted. After some monitoring I've discovered that it's happening because those two machines are being assigned different IP addresses every couple of days. If I remote into them and restart the node it reconnects and works fine.
My question is whether there's any (easy) way I can set the grid up to automatically detect IP address changes in the nodes and attempt to restart them.
